# Dynamic path helpers rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What are the paths that is automatically added by Rails? Let say you have a Question resource you automatically get questions_path, question_path etc. Where do I see what they resolve to and what I get?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This section might be helpful http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use

```
Verb    Path              Action     Helper

GET     /photos           index      photos_path
GET     /photos/new       new        new_photo_path
POST    /photos           create     photos_path
GET     /photos/:id       show       photo_path(:id)
GET     /photos/:id/edit  edit       edit_photo_path(:id)
PUT     /photos/:id       update     photo_path(:id)
DELETE  /photos/:id       destroy    photo_path(:id)
```

If you want to create a helper for `show` action you can write

```
photo_path(@photo.id)
```

where `@photo` is your model object. Or you can pass `@photo` directly if it responds to `id` method.

```
photo_path(@photo)
edit_photo_path(@photo)
```

You can also load `rails console` (in terminal) and test routes using `app` like so `app.photo_path(1)` (it will show you the route for the photo with `id` equals `1`)

Answer (score 10):

Just use:

```
rake routes
```

This will list all routes defined. The first column is relevant for you path helpers.

Comment: [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#seeing-existing-routes-with-rake) is the detailed explanation what `rake routes` gives you

Comment: I can't see how this shows what I can pass as arguments to the helper etc??

Comment: Updating @AmitPatel's comment for current versions of Rails: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following in your routes file:

```
resources :questions
```

Then Rails provides the following restful routes for you:

```
GET     /questions          index       list of questions
GET     /questions/new      new         show new question form
POST    /questions          create      create a new question
GET     /questions/:id      show        show a specific question
GET     /questions/:id/edit edit        show form to edit question
PUT     /questions/:id      update      update a specific question
DELETE  /questions/:id      destroy     delete a specific question
```

You can also run rake:routes to see what is being generated.