# How to send user to their profile as soon as they sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model that is related to devise. The Userinfo model belongs_to the User model. The userinfo model takes in some information(name, email, school...) through a form. Right now, as soon as the user signs up or signs in, the program checks if the current_user has filled out the information, if not, they will be routed to fill out the info page. If they have filled out the information, they will be routed to the home page, which is the userinfo index page. The index page shows the userinfo of all the users on the site.

The way the routing works:

Userinfo model:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :videos, through: :user

    def info_complete?
        name? && email? && college? && gpa? && major?
    end
end
```

Application controller:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.userinfo.info_complete?
      root_path
    else 
      new_user_info_path
    end
  end
```

**PROBLEM**

When the user signs in, if the user has the userinfo filled out, I want it to go to the user's profile page, not the index or the root path. The profile path is "userinfo#show". For userinfo#index, no id is needed, but to go to the "userinfo#show", and id is needed. because userinfo#index is '/userinfos', while userinfos#show is '/userinfos/userinfo_id'. My question is, how do I route the user to the userinfo#show, profile page, as soon as they sign in and if the userinfo data is filled out?

It might be simple but I feel like I'm missing something. How do I get access to the current userinfo_id in the application controller? so I can route it like:

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.userinfo.info_complete?
      userinfo_path(current_user.userinfo_id)
    else 
      new_user_info_path
    end
  end
```

Or something similar to the above?

Answer (score 1):

As in the answer to this question
[Dynamic path helpers rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863305/dynamic-path-helpers-rails)

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.userinfo.info_complete?
    user_info_path(current_user.userinfo_id)
  else 
    new_user_info_path
  end
end
```